# Rep cap today for me is 201 - is this a bug?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

Look at my reputation today (+231):

[image]

I got two accept ticks, which award me 30 reps in total. Therefore, I got 231 − 30 = 201 reps for votes received.

I don't get any reputation from the upvote on top, that means I hit my rep cap today, i.e. I can only gain reputation by acceptance or bounties, etc.

Therefore I see that I hit the rep cap at 201 rep, not 200 rep.

What's wrong?

Take note of the 21 rep I received for [Improve appearance of matrices as arrow labels in tikz-cd](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/480087/156344). I think it should be 20 rep.

Quite surprisingly, [/reputation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/reputation) is correct:

[image]

Comment: Looking at the details of this post: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIavi.png -> really odd

Comment: @samcarter Yes, and I can't figure it out. Of course with 6441 rep I can get to the palindromic 6446 easier, but this is strange.

Comment: @JouleV: Did you receive a downvote on any of your posts (questions) *today*? For example, any of these questions: [Welcoming 2019 Pi day: How to draw the letter π?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/479395/5764), [Welcoming 2019 Lunar New Year: How to draw a (lovely) pig?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/473287/5764), [3-level Verse in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462211/5764), [How to create a title page like this?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/459025/5764)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/reputation` report is an on-the-fly calculation of what your reputation should be. The information on the user profile comes from a rep history table that is rebuilt periodically.

Your account was scheduled for a rep recalc (that typically happens overnight unless triggered by something else - like a post deletion) to correct that 1 point discrepancy. I went ahead and kicked it off now, though, so both reports should be in sync now.

Comment: @marmot Unfortunately, there's not much I can do about that. There are a few ways we could show voting corrections, but none of them are without tradeoffs. Your account was also scheduled for a recalc and I ran it now, so I think that made things a little bit better... but that's the extent of what's possible here.

Comment: Thanks! ;-) ;-)